# Inherit from two parents with same members

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have three classes; A, B and C:

```
class A
{
    public:
        A() {}
    protected:
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
};

class B
{
    public:
        B() {}
    protected:
        int x = 1;
        int y = 1;
};

class C : public A, B
{
    public :
        C() {}
};
```

I want x member of C to be the one from A, and y member of C to me that from B. How can I do this? Since I've written `class C : public A, B`, now both C.x and C.y are 0. I have this problem in general when I have multiple inheritance and I want to inherit some members from one parent and some members from the other. Is there an option similar to the one for member functions, where one can use the keyword `using` to choose which function will be used?

Comment: You can get access to the variables you want with `A::x` and `B::y` here: [https://ideone.com/F4oJ5h](https://ideone.com/F4oJ5h)

Comment: @drescherjm Is there an option similar to the one for member functions, where one can use the keyword `using` to "choose" which function will be used?

Comment: You can't inherit some members from one and some from another. You inherit *all* members from both. A `C` is an `A` so it must have both `x` and `y` from `A`.  A `C` is also a `B` so it must also have both `x` and `y` from `B`. You can see that `sizeof(C) == sizeof(A) + sizeof(B)` (and there shouldn't be any padding).

Comment: Can you create a base class for A and B (called BaseAB) with pure virtual methods `int &GetX() = 0;` and `int &GetY() = 0;` and implement appropriately?

Answer (score 2):

> now both `C.x` and `C.y` are `0`

Actually, `C::x` and `C::y` are both ambiguous and won't compile. You can explicitly select and expose members from base classes with `using`:

```cpp
class C : public A, B
{
    public :
        C() {}

        using A::x;
        using B::y;
};
```

Comment: This is not solving my problem. Maybe I've simplified my problem way too much, but I actually have four classes, like a diamond problem. In this case,  both C.x and C.y are 0, and the using word is not causing any effect

Comment: @kubo It seems to be the case. Feel free to edit your question with a sample that fits your actual issue better. Edit: well, now we're a crowd in here. Maybe a new question would be clearer.

Comment: I have posted a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/q/69033631/14363307. Could you please check it out?

Answer (score 2):

> I want to inherit some members from one parent and some members from the other.

That you can't do. All members will be inherited. `C` has `A::x`,`A::y`, `B::x` and `B::y`.

> Is there an option similar to the one for member functions, where one can use the keyword `using`.

You can help the compiler to resolve the ambiguity (see [Quentin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69015940/7582247)) but the fact is that you still inherit all of the members.

```
class C : public A, B {
public :
    using A::x;
    using B::y;

    C() {
        std::cout << x << '\n';    // 0
        std::cout << y << '\n';    // 1

        // these are still here though:
        std::cout << A::x << '\n'; // 0
        std::cout << A::y << '\n'; // 0
        std::cout << B::x << '\n'; // 1
        std::cout << B::y << '\n'; // 1
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to inherit some members from one parent

It isn't possible to inherit "some members". You can only inherit a base in its entirety. In the example, the class `C` indirectly contains both `C::A::y` and `C::B::y` as well as the two `x` members.

> now both C.x and C.y are 0.

Actually, now there is no `C::x` nor `C::y` because those names are ambiguous.

> is there an option similar to the one for member functions, where one can use the keyword using

Yes, you can use `using` to make the names `C::x` and `C::y` unambiguous. It will hide the "unused" names, but the objects don't go away. Same as with member functions.

---

You should change the design. You could do something like this for example:

```
struct Ax {
    int x = 0;
};
struct Ay {
    int y = 0;
};
struct A : Ax, Ay {};

struct Bx {
    int x = 1;
};
struct By {
    int y = 1;
};
struct B : Bx, By {};

struct C : Ax, By {};
```