# Inheritance from parents with same members

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I am having trouble accessing members (with the same name) of parents under multiple inheritance. I have 4 classes (classic diamond problem) defined as follows:

```
class ClapTrap
{
    public:
        ClapTrap(void)
        { _hitpoints = 0; }
        ~ClapTrap() { }

    protected:
        int             _hitpoints;
};

class ScravTrap : public virtual ClapTrap
{
    public:
        ScravTrap(void)
        { _hitpoints = 1; }
        ~ScravTrap() { }
};

class FragTrap : public virtual ClapTrap
{
    public:
        FragTrap(void)
        { _hitpoints = 2; }
        ~FragTrap() { }
};

class DiamondTrap : public ScravTrap, public FragTrap
{
    public:
        DiamondTrap(void)
        { 
            std::cout << ScravTrap::_hitpoints << std::endl;
            std::cout << FragTrap::_hitpoints << std::endl;
        }
        ~DiamondTrap() { }
};


int main()
{
    DiamondTrap d;
}
```

The output of my main is

```
2
2
```

I expected this output to be

```
1
2
```

because the first time I am printing the ScravTrap::_hitpoints member of DiamondTrap (and ScrapTrap::_hitpoints is initialized to 1) and the second time I am printing the FragTrap::_hitpoints member of DiamondTrap (which has previously been initialized to 2). I know that DiamondTrap inherits both _hitpoint members, but how can I access them properly?

**NOTE** Even if I write `using ScravTrap::_hitpoints` at the beginning of the public part of my DiamondTrap class, the output is still the same. Why is this happening?

**EDIT** Some of the answers mention that virtual inheritance generates only one copy of the base class. I want to call the constructor of ClapTrap only once when creating an instance of DiamondTrap. How can I do this and also have access to both ScravTrap::_hitpoints and FragTrap::_hitpoints? What if I have two members in each parent class? Can DiamondTrap inherit on of them from FragTrap and one of them from ScravTrap? How can I do this?

Comment: What does `virtual` inheritance accomplish?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Plus: In which order are the base classes initialized?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica It makes sure there is only one `ClapTrap`.

Comment: ... which means...

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica & kubo There's only _one_ `ClapTrap` and with that, only one `_hitpoints `

Comment: @TedLyngmo: I'm pretty sure StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica knows the answer :-) Question was for OP. Improved [Rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) :-)

Comment: @Jarod42 True.  I didn't really pick up on the tone of the questions. :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo - Poe's law. Every time :)

Comment: *"How can I do this and also have access to both `ScravTrap::_hitpoints` and `FragTrap::_hitpoints`?"* either you have virtual inheritance, and `ScravTrap::_hitpoints` and `FragTrap::_hitpoints` are the same variable, or you use non virtual inheritance ("Y inheritance") to have 2 `ClapTrap` (so a constructor call for each, for a total of 2).

Comment: I think you need to explain what you are trying to accomplish in more detail. What's the purpose of only having one constructor call if you want one `_hitpoints` for every time you inherit `ClapTrap`?

Comment: "_What if I have two members in each parent class? Can DiamondTrap inherit on of them from FragTrap and one of them from ScravTrap? How can I do this?_" - No, you can't inherit only a part of a base class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only *one* `ClapTrap` since you use `virtual` inheritance and with that, only one `_hitpoints`.

You can't have that one `_hitpoints` variable carry multiple values.

First, `ClapTrap` is constructed, assigning `0`, then `ScravTrap` is constructed, assigning `1` and last, `FragTrap` is constructed, assigning `2` -  all to the same `_hitpoints` variable.

> I want to call the constructor of `ClapTrap` only once when creating an instance of `DiamondTrap`.

That is what you do right now.

> How can I do this and also have access to both `ScravTrap::_hitpoints` and `FragTrap::_hitpoints`?

You can't. You'll have to select one or the other.

Without `virtual` inheritance, you'll have two constructor calls and `ScravTrap::_hitpoints` and `FragTrap::_hitpoints`.

With `virtual` inheritance, you'll have one constructor call and only one `_hitpoints`.

Comment: ... and it will carry the value last assigned to it, by the constructor last run, which is the last one in the list of base classes, which assigns 2.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Good point. I added the construction schema to the answer.

Comment: What if I have two members in each parent class? Can DiamondTrap inherit on of them from FragTrap and one of them from ScravTrap? How can I do this?

Comment: "_two members in each parent class_" - Four member variables in total? I don't see what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

> I expected this output to be
>
> ```
> 1
> 2
> ```

One `int` object cannot have two different values at the same time, so this output is not possible.

> know that DiamondTrap inherits both _hitpoint members

There is only one `ClapTrap` and thus only one `_hitpoint` member.

> Why is this happening?

This is happening because you use virtual inheritance. `_hitpoints` is first initialised with indeterminate value in the constructor of the virtual base `ClapTrap` which then assigns it to 0. After that, the constructor of base `ScravTrap` assigns it to 1 and lastly, the constructor of base `FragTrap` assigns it to 2.

> want to call the constructor of ClapTrap only once when creating an instance of DiamondTrap. How can I do this and also have access to both ScravTrap::_hitpoints and FragTrap::_hitpoints?

Remove the member from `ClapTrap` and add the member to `ScravTrap` and `FragTrap` would achieve what you want. It's unclear why you want this.